# Core Animation Bar

Tags: objective-c, graphics, core-animation, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

Currently I have an image... A battery Icon...

```
_MeterBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 40, 50, 40)];
_MeterBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"battery-empty-icon.png"];
_MeterBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I am attempting to add an animation that shows the battery loading to a specific point of the battery when a value is fetched from a web server.

Fetching the value is no problem but adding the animation is an issue. I basically copied and pasted some code a user answered before but I am stuck :/. When I add the animation, there is no image.....

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleToValue = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
scaleToValue.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0f];
scaleToValue.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
scaleToValue.duration = 1.0f;
scaleToValue.delegate = self;
_MeterBar.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
[_MeterBar.layer addAnimation:scaleToValue forKey:@"scaleRight"];
CGAffineTransform scaleTo = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 50.0f);
_MeterBar.transform = scaleTo;

[_PowerNowView addSubview:_MeterBar];
```

The battery icon is more wide than tall so I'm animating from 0 -> a percentage on the x axis.

If anyone has any hints, tips, or sample examples that does this exact animation, I would greatly appreciate your help :)

Thank you.

P.S. Heres the URL of the battery Icon i found : [Battery Icon](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-9/256/battery-empty-icon.png)

Sorry for not being clear but I would like to have a color layer seperate of the battery icon...

I would like to create a bar over the battery image and have the bar dynamically animate with respect to the size of the battery.... not actually resize the battery image itself....

So there would be two layers, one for the battery that is mainly static in size and the other layer being the colored BAR, maybe a green color to represent the amount of the BATTERY image that is filled.

A good reference of what I would like to do is what the MINT application does, whose purpose is to  record your bank statements.

[image: Final Animation]

The final animated battery above is very nice but I would just like to show a bar within the battery and animate it with respect to the pulled data value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

Your scale of 100 would make your layer 100 times larger than normal. If it's 300 pixels on a side, a scale of 100 would display it as 30,000 pixels on a side.

You want your to scale value to 1.0, not 100.

Also, I'm not sure if scaling the transform multiplies the previous scale by a growing factor. If it does, then a starting scale value of 0 would prevent it from ever growing, since anything times zero is still zero. Try a from value of .0001 instead of 0.0,

If you want your battery image to grow from left to right, wouldn't you want your anchor point to be (0,.5) rather than (.5, 1)?

And, when you change the anchor point, it not only changes the center for transforms, but it moves the position of the image. You will need to adjust the position to compensate. I always have to scratch my head and think about it really hard (and usually get it wrong anyway) but I think you would want to shift the X position of your view to the right by half of it's width.

Note that scaling your image will cause it to stretch oddly. It will start out short and fat and stretch out to normal size.

It might be better to attach a CAShapeLayer to the view as a mask layer, and animate the shape layer's path from an empty rectangle (Width = 0, height = full height of view) to a rectangle that is the full size of the view. That would cause the view to animate in a "wipe" animation where it is revealed from left to right without stretching.